# Polling a Celery Task with Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, celery

I have a Celery task that populates a PostgreSQL database over the course of a few minutes. I want to retrieve the current data from the database in a Django view and send it to a template where it will be constantly re-displayed according to the progress of the task. So, I want to update the template in real-time.

Currently, I have a view that calls the Celery task and gets the result of the task. It then renders the template and sends it the result of the task in the form of a string, as well as the id of the task.

I am not very familiar with AJAX, but from what I've read I will need another view that AJAX will call to retrieve the most up-to-date result of the task.

Here is the code so far:

View that renders the template:

```
def dashboard(request):
    result = prepare_database.delay()
    return render(request, 'appname/template.html',
                      {'task_id': result.task_id})
```

View that gets the current data

```
def current_data(request):
    task_id = request.GET.get('task_id')
    if task_id:
        async_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
        return JsonResponse({'data': async_result.get()})
```

Ajax to poll the task (again, very new to AJAX):

```
function pollTaskStatus(taskId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/current_data/',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            task_id: taskId  
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'in_progress') {

            } else {
                // Update the HTML with the results
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var taskId = '{{ task_id }}';  // Get the task ID from the template
    pollTaskStatus(taskId);
});
```

Please let me know if my entire approach is flawed, as I am not too sure this is the right way to go. Is everything currently setup correctly? Also, let me know if there is anything else I should clarify or elaborate on.